# SherlockListFragment 'onCreateOptionMenu' crashes on android 2.3.3

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-listfragment, android-menu

I have a generic `SherlockListFragment` that is used in my App in different cases.
This fragment has a Option Menu Item ( a `SearchView`), here is the code of the `SearchView` creation:

```
    @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu, final MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.all_places, menu);

    final MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    searchMenuItem.setOnActionExpandListener(this);

    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchMenuItem
            .getActionView();
    searchView.requestFocusFromTouch();
    searchView.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.search_query_hint));
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

}
```

The problem is that one of this fragments instances is used in a ViewPager, and when swiping to it, the app crashes (only on HTC Desire with android 2.3.3), but works on ICS and JB devices. By the way, when attaching the fragment manually (with no `ViewPager`) no crash occurs.

Here is the stack trace of the crash:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:6132)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:1213)
    at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:6116)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.restoreActionViewStates(MenuBuilder.java:361)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.preparePanel(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:503)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.dispatchInvalidateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:272)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.invalidateOptionsMenu(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:150)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:156)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setMenuVisibility(Fragment.java:781)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.setPrimaryItem(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:151)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1009)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:880)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:238)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm really stuck with this issue... any help will be great.

**Edit**

Switched to ActionBarSherlock dev branch - no crash... thanks everybody.

Comment: what do you mean by imports?

Comment: All libraries and library projects are imported correctly. And the source code uses correct imports.

Comment: "the app crashes (only on HTC Desire with android 2.3.3), but works on ICS and JB devices" suggests that you have imported wrong APIs. E.g. `android.view.MenuInflater` vs `android.support.v4.view.MenuInflater`

Comment: Have you tried the `dev` version of ABS? It fixed something similar to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
private editTextSearch;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);       
    menu.getItem(0).setActionView(R.layout.search); //Number of menu item
    editTextSearch = (EditText) menu.getItem(0).getActionView().findViewById(R.id.edit_search); //Your editetxt search

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```